# How to create a method from another method?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to to find the best practice for telling the ts compiler that a method will be created at run time.

```ts
interface Todo { /* ... */ }

export class TodoModel {
 todos: Todo[] = [];
 
 constructor() {
//...
 }

 bindTodoListChanged(callback : (todos: Todo[]) => void) {
   this.onTodoListChanged = callback
 }

 _save(todos: Todo[]) {
   this.onTodoListChanged(todos)
   localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
 }

}
```

I currently receive this error:

```
 Property 'onTodoListChanged' does not exist on type 'TodoModel'. Did you mean 'bindTodoListChanged'?
```

I thought using an assert `!` would help

```ts
 bindTodoListChanged(callback : (todos: Todo[]) => void) {
   this.onTodoListChanged! = callback
 }

 _commit(todos: Todo[]) {
   this.onTodoListChanged(todos)
   localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
 }
```

I've also tried

```ts
onTodoListChanged(todos: Todo[]): void

 bindTodoListChanged(callback : (todos: Todo[]) => void) {
   this.onTodoListChanged! = callback
 }

 _commit(todos: Todo[]) {
   this.onTodoListChanged(todos)
   localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
 }
```

Which produced this error:

```
Function implementation name must be 'onTodoListChanged'.
```

Lastly, I've tried `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` in my `tsconfig.json` But I would prefer to not have to alter the config.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WYeKvW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: You need to _define the property_, as you've done (pointlessly, as it never gets assigned to or read from) with `todos`. You should also deal with the fact that it could not have been assigned by the time `_save` is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the [class field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#fields) `onTodoListChanged`, presumably as an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) because it might not exist:

```
class TodoModel {
    /* ⋯ */
    onTodoListChanged?: (todos: Todo[]) => void
    /* ⋯ */
}
```

This will stop the compiler from complaining that `onTodoListChanged` doesn't exist:

```
bindTodoListChanged(callback: (todos: Todo[]) => void) {
    this.onTodoListChanged = callback // okay
}
```

Because it's optional, you'll have to check that it's not `undefined` before calling it; the easiest way to do that is probably to use the [optional chaining operator (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#optional_chaining_with_function_calls):

```
_save(todos: Todo[]) {
    this.onTodoListChanged?.(todos) // okay
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsAm7kG9kD0AVMgHTnJEHIC+AUHRAB4AO6UYyCANnAM580WdAFksEbnjrIZyMML4AuIdgDaAXWQBeZBoDc02ehAZsAGWB8wAYQAWcEAHMImAPzKAFPOxKV6DQCU2gB8yABu6MCYhjIIxlZQAK4I8lAeQfj0McgARqCYpugWVnYOzpgeCHDc3DmIANae3ui+hYEh4ZGYGdmycraWpMaFxTb2Ti7aXNW1DdlZfQD6fHBhEF4Kym3qPX19YAN8QybCo6UTbqQbPgG9stzoVdwAyqlwzqR8EGAAkpAAth4AOTNPhAgA0yAAUs8APIAOU+YCgoEcwBgAE9ri0Arc+vQaEA)